# What is the method to detect whether a given picture is human face or not?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Is there any simple algorithm to judge whether a given image is face or something else (without training hopefully)?

My thought is to construct the eigenvectors of each image, then apply some clustering method (for example k-means with k = 2). But I'm not sure what will be the best criteria to distinguish face/non-face even if a good clustering result is obtained?

Comment: without training - no way. opencv is using haar/lbp boosted-cascade-classifiers for face *detection* and eigenvalues/LBPH features for *recognition* (but no clustering for the latter at all, straight nearest neighbour)

Comment: [Some test images once you're done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia)

Comment: It will be pretty tough to do that without any training, however there are sample face classifier out there which you can use, however, robustness and accuracy may not be that excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eigen decomposition reduces dimensionality in continues domain by finding directions in data space with high variance. K-means finds clusters in space with high density of points. You kind of mixing them together while completely ignoring how would you arrive at the face features on the first place (how would you scale, rotate and crop whatever you want to inspect either).

You don’t need to train Haar detectors since they are already trained for faces. They detect a face, not recognize its identity. ALl you need is to port the code together with a little file with parameters obtained after training (that was already performed) as Shiva suggested above.

Thoughtless copy-pasting of the code doesn’t make much sense though. Read a bit about [Haar](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=haar#cv.HaarDetectObjects). Try to understand

1. Why they work - faces have features most pronounced on the intermediate spatial scale such as eyes, nose, brows. Too small (size of the pupil) or too large (size of the whole face) features are less useful.
2. why Haars are preferred to wavelets or Gabors - Haars are just raw (boxy) approximations of Gabors but since they can be quickly calculated with [Integral images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) they are preferred to more precise but slower counterparts;
3. what are the restrictions - Haars have their own spatial scale and orientation but can be quickly recalculated for another scale.
4. How to train Haar classifier (the most exciting topic you are trying to avoid). [Ada boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) is the one way to train a more complex classifier consisting of several Haars. Finally to speed up processing you can ask a slightly different question instead of *find me a face*. Namely, you can try to quickly eliminate the areas in the image that cannot be a face. This is called a cascade classification. Study these aspects in a systematic way and you will learn more about face detection than you’d do from the code pasting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Haar classifier method for face detection in an image/video frame.

A sample code for finding faces in an images will be like this

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img;
    img = cvLoadImage( "dasl_hubo.jpg" );
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    // Note that you must copy C:\Program Files\OpenCV\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml or where opencv is installed
    // to your working directory

    CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );

    double scale = 1.3;

    static CvScalar colors[] = { {{0,0,255}}, {{0,128,255}}, {{0,255,255}}, 
    {{0,255,0}}, {{255,128,0}}, {{255,255,0}}, {{255,0,0}}, {{255,0,255}} };// this will draw rectangles of these colors around the detected faces.

    // Detect objects
    cvClearMemStorage( storage );
    CvSeq* objects = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage, 1.1, 4, 0, cvSize( 40, 50 ));

    CvRect* r;
    // Loop through objects and draw boxes
    for( int i = 0; i < (objects ? objects->total : 0 ); i++ ){
        r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( objects, i );
        cvRectangle( img, cvPoint( r->x, r->y ), cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
            colors[i%8]);
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "Output" );
    cvShowImage( "Output", img );
    cvWaitKey();

    cvReleaseImage( &img );

    return 0;
}
```

visit these links to find more about face detection using harr cascades

[drexel.edu](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut11.html)

[opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)

[presentation on Harr training and usages](http://users.utcluj.ro/~tmarita/HCI/C7-8-extra/Face-detect/facedetect.pdf)

Comment: oh, please *don't* point noobs at the deprecated c-api, they moved to c++ years ago, and noone should write code like this anymore.

Comment: @berak: 1st of all if you jot a better answer just post, 2nd its just for keeping things simple,some one here is asking how detect faces and this is the simplest of the answers, coz I still believe that you start something with a **hello world** program and not by say **How to create an OS**

Comment: @Shiva thank you very much for your answer. I upvoted back for you. But I was wondering whether there are any unsupervised algorithms on this problem? Note that I don't need to recognize image A is Alice, B is Bob, I just want to be sure that A and B are both human faces. Thank you.

Comment: @ChuNan: There are quite a few of them(mostly as research) but I have used none, as far as face detection goes Harr Cascade also just catches faces(assuming its a harr cascade for faces) and does not recognize them.You also get a generic Harr file with opencv itself that will suit the propose.

Comment: @ChuNan: If you want to recognize A as Alice and B as Bob or someone specifically then only you need to train your own Harr file other wise for most of the purposes the standard one does fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my opencv code in C++, it is simple to detect faces in an image with the help of Opencv haar-like feature, you may refer to the documents for the usage of some methods in it. I hope it helps.

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;  //for read in haar-like faces database in opencv
std::vector<Rect> faces;         //for storing detected faces
vector<Point2d> FaceCenter;      //for storing centres of faces

Mat frame_gray = imread(“/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx.jpg”, CV_8UC1);  //read the image in gray-scale;

equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );                       //histogram to extract the contrast

String face_cascade_name = "/Users/xxx/opencv-2.4.7/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"; //path of the trained faces .xml file

if(!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))  //load the .xml
{
    cout << "face_casacade.xml load error" << endl;
}

face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0, Size(50, 50) ); //Detect faces in the image

for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    Point2d center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5); //store centres of faces
    FaceCenter.push_back(center);

    int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 ); //circle the faces in the image, optional
    ellipse( frame_gray, center, Size( eyes[j].width*0.5, eyes[j].height*0.25), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 2, 8, 0 );
}

imshow(“Faces Detection”, frame_gray); //show the result
```